# Dart: object property based on another object of the same class

Tags: dart, oop, properties

I am struggling to find a sound solution in Dart for this concept:

- multiple objects of the same class
- objectB has a property dependent on a property of objectA
- property of objectB is a calculation based on a fixed double property of objectA
- I prefer to store the actual calculated value in the property of objectB - not only the definition

Example implementation:

```
class Item {
  // unique identifier of an object, UUID etc
  String id = '';
  double price = 0;
  // flag of and object with calculated property
  bool isCalculated = false;
  // id of the object which this object depends on
  String dependsOn = '';
  // percentage of price of the linked object
  double percentage = 1;

  // logic for calculating the price on-the-fly if isCalculated is true?

  Item(
      {required this.id,
      this.price = 0,
      this.dependsOn = '',
      this.isCalculated = false,
      this.percentage = 1});
}

void main() {
  Item item1 = Item(id: 'aaa', price: 10);

  Item item2 = Item(
    id: 'bbb',
    isCalculated: true,
    dependsOn: 'aaa',
    percentage: 0.1,
  );
}
```

I am pretty sure there is no direct language support, it is more a conceptual issue. I though about:

- using a getter for a price and calculate it internally, the requestor does not know if the object is calculated or not
- in that case I am not sure how to implement updating the value if the value of objectA has changed

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like caching the result of a computation, and cache invalidation if the base value changes.
As they say: [There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)

What I'd do is:

- Link item B directly to item A.
- Have a variable for the computation.
- Have a variable with enough information to see if the computation is still valid.
- Have a getter which checks if the computation is available and still valid, and otherwise computes it again.

That only makes sense if the computation is *very* expensive. Otherwise I'd just compute it in the getter every time it's needed.

Comment: thanks for the "two hard things" :)

I mostly struggle with the first point - how to "link" items together. There is no direct language support or a straighforward workaround for binding the property of objectA to objectB, right?

Comment: You can do `class Item { ... Item _itemA; ... int get percent => compute(_itemA.propery); ... }`. Store a reference to objectA on objectB. Make a getter on objectB which reads values through that reference when doing the computation. Thats's standard OO representation of a dependency between two objects.